# Datagridview date to label formatting issue

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am almost embarrassed to ask this.  I would like to take a date from my `DataGridView` named `salesOrdersDataGridView` and write it to a label on a `Form`. I format the date to short date in my sql query and it displays correctly in the `DataGridView`. Trouble is, when I use this code:

```
string shp= "";
shp = salesOrdersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["shipDate"].Value.ToString();
lblshp.Text = shp;
```

The label displays the long date/time (with hours and minutes).  I know there is a simple solution - but I am just not getting it. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the type of the value in the datagridview? datetime? or a simple string? If it is a string can you please show the format?

Comment: I am using VS2015 and the type is set up in properties - ColumnType = DataGridViewTextBoxColumn. I hope this answers your question

Comment: " I hope this answers your question" not really, but I can deduce the type from your statement that `ToString()` results in the output of date plus time.

Comment: how do you populate your datagridview? Do you databind it? If yes what type is the column in your sql table? Date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime shp = DateTime.Parse(salesOrdersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["shipDate"].Value.ToString());

lblshp.Text = shp.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

Parse your value as a datetime first and use the toString method to format it